# What examples are there for the "closest pair of points"?

Tags: algorithm, points, closest

I'm looking for a motivational example for the "closest pair of points problem"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem

In itself it's a pretty self explanatory problem, but I can't find a reasonable case where such an algorithm with o(n log n) would be needed over the brute force approach in o (n<sup>2</sup>).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Reasonable case for using an O(nlogn) algorithm over O(n^2) is every case that handles such a large number of elements that O(n^2) takes more time to execute than O(nlogn). For instance, brute force O(n^2) with 1 million elements may take about half an hour to solve, while divine & conquer O(nlogn) algorithm takes only some seconds. A very quick way to see the difference (1million ^2) and (1million * log2(1million)), you can see the huge difference there.